# Firebase + collection-repeat = error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

Now I'm working with Ionic framework and I have noticed, that `ng-repeat` is too slow. Fortunatly, `collection-repeat`, that was made by Ionic is much better for perfomance.

But i have a trouble with `collection-repeat`. I load my data from Firebase using Angularfire. When I'm using `ng-repeat` everything is working great, but with `collection-repeat`, there is an error :(

My JS code:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
        var authRef = new Firebase('https://#####.firebaseio.com/');
        $scope.dataObj = $firebaseObject(authRef);
})
```

My HTML code:

```
    <div class="card list" collection-repeat = "(id, element) in dataObj">
       <p>{{id}}</p>
    </div>
```

Error:

```
Error: collection-repeat expected an array for 'dataObj', but got a undefined
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `$firebaseAuth(authRef)` is returning `undefined` as the error said. If you can post the console output for `$firebaseAuth(authRef)` it would help me answer the question :)

Comment: @Burdock Thak's for answer) Yes, i know it. It's beacause data loading is not instantaneous. But apparently, ng-repeat can 'wait' for data, so can collection-repeat do the same?

Comment: $firebaseAuth() never returns undefined. There is not enough here to repro this issue. Either `dataObj` is being declared in a different scope than the call to collection-repeat, or $firebaseAuth has been extended/altered in some way.

Comment: @Kato Thousands of apologies! I've mixed up $firebaseAuth and $firebaseObject. Now everything is alright. Sorry!

Comment: Ah ha! Glad you resolved it.